# Google Maps Geochart US plus Puerto Rico

Tags: google-maps, google-visualization

I have made a map using google maps geochart that's working great with the united states. However I need to add in Puerto rico as well.

here is a link to the fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/u4h0w87h/1/

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["geochart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

  function drawRegionsMap() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['State', 'Assets Sold'],

        ['US-AK',1],
        ['US-AL',188],
        ['US-AR',72],
        ['US-AZ',86],
        ['US-CA',375],
        ['US-CO',108],
        ['US-CT',12]            

    ]);

    var options = {region: 'US', resolution: 'provinces', displaymode: 'regions'};

    var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

How can I keep what I have now and add in Puerto rico to the map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can not have US states and Puerto Rico highlighted at the same time since Puerto Rico is considers a country under [ISO 3166-1 alpha-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2)

Geocharts doesn't support highlighting states and countries at the same time.

Comment: Yeah. After a few hours of searching I also found that the heatmap function will not support this. I was able to do this using one of the other settings. But it did not meet the requirements I needed. Plus it looks horrible. Thanks.